# Black Background When Scroll Up Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

In my project I used a navigation controller embedding a table view controller. But when I scroll up the table view a black background shows up (as shown in the .gif below)

how can I fix this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What is the backgroundColor property of your viewController ?

Comment: @Poql it seems that view controllers have no color property, but the background color of all views have been set as white

Comment: Sure. Even the backgroundColor of your tableView ?

Comment: @Poql yeah, I just checked that

Comment: Also check your code. It looks like your bar is a bit black with the transparency it must be the controller's view or something behind your tavleView. You can use view debugging (available since Xcode 6) to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution myself. In case someone else has the same problem, here's what to do:

- Select your table view
- Go to Attribute Inspector
- Find the Scroll View section and change the Style property to white

[image]

Comment: not work for me i have one view in that view i took scroll view and inside scroll view i took another view and in that view i took all other tools.... got me ?

Answer (score 0):

set the properties of scrollview background color as white

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I added following codes:

```
yourTableView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set background color to table view in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.backgroundColor = .white
}
```